# save multiple request in laravel at same time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to store this data in the database at the same time

[image]

i do that but i get error:Array to string conversion

```
    $usersId = $request['user_id'];
    $teachers_id = $request['teacher_id'];
    $courses_id = $request['course_id'];
    $status = $request['status'];
    $date = $request['date'];
    $time = $request['time'];
    $jalasat = $request['jalasat'];


    try {

        foreach ($usersId as $userId) {
           $savedata = Attendance::create(
                [
                    'user_id' => $userId,
                    'teacher_id' => $teachers_id,
                    'course_id' => $courses_id,
                    'status' => $status,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'time' => $time,
                    'jalasat' => $jalasat
                ]
            );
```

Comment: You have to use `for loop` to perform your action

Comment: could you be more explicit, for example the controller method for store, the models involve in this, any relation info...please?

Comment: Please never post textual details as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to insert those data as multiple rows you can use a loop.

```
foreach ($request->user_id as $index => $user_id) {
    $savedata = Attendance::create([
        "user_id" => $request->user_id[$index],
        "course_id" => $request->course_id[$index],
        "jalasat" => $request->jalasat[$index],
        "date" => $request->date[$index],
        "time" => $request->time[$index],
        "status" => $request->status[$index],
    ]);
}
```

If you can share your table structure that's will be good for an answer this question.
Any further queries, you can comment on this answer.